# cant get a jquery mobile dialog to show

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the library 1.1. I am trying to get a simple dialog to display, I dont want to load a page I just want to show a div tags content from the same page.

Do I need to add any special jquery references other than the standard 1.1 reference?

Lets say I have this

```
   <a href="#dialog" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade" data-inline="true">Find</a>

        <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h1>Foo</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
                <p>Bar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What do I need to do to a page to get when clicking the button the dialog to appear?

Full output html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Plenfy</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="/Content/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"      />
```

```
        <img src="/Content/mobile/images/logo-80.png"/>
 <p>
 </p>
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="/Account/join">Join</a></li>
<li><a href="/Account/Login">Log In</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>   
       </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="start">
            <a href="#dialog" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade" data-inline="true">Find</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h1>Foo</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
                <p>Bar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        ?



    </div>

</div>

<script src="/Scripts/mobile/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: so you want the dialog to load/display first before the page is displayed?

Comment: Updated my answer: You have to include jQuery Mobile JS after including jQuery 1.7.1. In your html you are only including jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css but missing jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js. Also remove the script tag for jQuery 1.6.4 at the end of your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to include jQuery Mobile (css **AND js**) and jQuery core 1.6.4 **OR** 1.7.1 as stated in the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/getting-started.html).

And make sure your page structure is valid:

```
<div data-role="page" id="start"> 
    <a href="#dialog" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade" data-inline="true">Find</a>
</div> 

<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
        <p>Bar</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

[Working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bgx7/1185/)

**Update according to your full html:**

Don't including jQuery 1.7.1 AND 1.6.4, remove the script tag for jQuery 1.6.4 and include **jQuery Mobile JS** instead after including jquery 1.7.1. Your includes should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: has @bas. I think everything is ok with my html, I copied yours over and still no joy. Just about to update to update my question with my actual html